# For loop output as an array

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I wrote a code in Matlab which I predefine the variable "a" and then set up a for loop of 5 iterations where the variable "a" goes through some basic operations. However, the for loop output only saves the fifth iteration of "a." How do I save all 5 iterations in a 1x5 array?

The code is as follows:

```
a = 10;
k = 0.5;
n = 2;
for m = 1:5
    a = a + (a*k) + n;
end
```

Edit:
I just found it that I have to create a new variable.

```
a = 10;
k = 0.5;
n = 2;
a_n = zeros(1,5);

for m = 1:5
    a = a + (a*k) + n;
    a_n(m) = a;
end
```

Comment: .. What language is that? Without knowing, I don't know what the syntax is to create an array. (Of course you could use Google with "[language] array".)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the language is in Matlab.

Comment: Declaration of new variable `a_n = zeros(1,5);` is redundant in Matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to store value of `a` after each iteration into an another variable `x`

```
a = 10;
k = 0.5;
n = 2;
for m = 1:5
    a = a + (a*k) + n;
    x(m) = a;
end
x
```

Output:

```
x =
    17.000    27.500    43.250    66.875   102.312
```

Comment: The array syntax is correct on this answer. This should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a different variable to store the 5 iterations as an array.

Code would look something like this:

```
a = 10;
k = 0.5;
n = 2;
b = [];
for m = 1:5
   a = (a + (a*k) + n)
   b = [b a];
end
```

You can now print `b` for all 5 iteration values.

Here is an alternate way to update values into the 1-D matrix.

Comment: How do you know what language this is?

Comment: Based on the syntax of for loop I guessed Matlab, but I could be wrong here.

Comment: Terry, please choose the other answer as the chosen answer, it has the proper array syntax. I'll update my answer with that change as well.

Comment: @PraveenramBalachandar apart from the syntax, your code won't give desired output. it's not storing previously processed value of `a` for next iteration

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that as well. Thanks, I'll fix it.